# Partition existing tables using PostgreSQL 10

Tags: database, postgresql, partitioning, database-administration

I have gone through a bunch of documentation for PostgresSQL 10 partitioning but I am still not clear on whether existing tables can be partitioned. Most of the posts mention about partitioning existing tables using PostgreSQL 9.

Also, in the official PostgresSQL website : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html, it mentions 'It is not possible to turn a regular table into a partitioned table or vice versa'.

So, my question is can existing tables be partitioned in PostgreSQL 10? 
If the answer is YES, my plan is :

1. Create a partitions
2. Alter the existing table to include the range so new data goes into the new partition. Once that is done, write a script which loops over the master table and moves the data into the right partitions.
3. Then, truncate the master table and enforce that nothing can be inserted into it.

If the answer is NO, my plan is to make the existing table the first partition

1. Create a new parent table and children(partitions).
2. Perform light transaction which will rename the existing table to a partition table name and the new parent to the actual table name.

Are there better ways to partition existing tables in PostgreSQL 10/9?

Comment: *Most of the posts mention about partitioning existing tables using PostgreSQL 9* -- that's because with the older, [inheritance way](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-IMPLEMENTATION-INHERITANCE) you can partition already existing tables as well (but of course it's kind of inconvenient, see [`ALTER TABLE ... [NO] INHERIT ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html)). With the new, declarative way in 10, you cannot do that. But your second idea seems fine to me.